# How to deploy AWS CDK stacks to multiple accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

AWS CDK stacks target an account or region based on an evironment, details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/environments.html).  Here is an example of an app that deploys one stack into multiple target accounts:

```
const envEU  = { account: '2383838383', region: 'eu-west-1' };
const envUSA = { account: '8373873873', region: 'us-west-2' };

new MyFirstStack(app, 'first-stack-eu', { env: envEU });
new MyFirstStack(app, 'first-stack-us', { env: envUSA });
```

My question is how to deploy these 2 stacks - is it possible to deploy them as a single operation? If so, what credentials are used and what roles are required on the 2 accounts?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do a single command to deploy all stacks across all accounts:

```
cdk deploy ...
```

Or is the deployment only possible via 2 steps?

```
cdk deploy first-stack-eu --profile=profile_for_account_2383838383
cdk deploy first-stack-us --profile=profile_for_account_8373873873
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up using the [cdk-assume-role-credential-plugin](https://github.com/aws-samples/cdk-assume-role-credential-plugin) to perform the task. The description of that plugin states:

> This plugin allows the CDK CLI to automatically obtain AWS credentials
> from a stack's target AWS account. This means that you can run a
> single command (i.e. cdk synth) with a set of AWS credentials, and the
> CLI will determine the target AWS account for each stack and
> automatically obtain temporary credentials for the target AWS account
> by assuming a role in the account.

I wrote up a detailed tutorial on how to use this plugin to perform AWS cross-account deployments using CDK here: https://johntipper.org/aws-cdk-cross-account-deployments-with-cdk-pipelines-and-cdk-assume-role-credential-plugin/

Comment: hey good stuff, but is this plugin written in python?

Answer (score 5):

In cloudformation you can use [Stack Sets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/what-is-cfnstacksets.html) for multi-account and multi-region deployments.

However, this is not yet supported in CDK according to the GitHub issue:

- [Support for CloudFormation StackSets #66](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk-rfcs/issues/66)

Comment: It's supported now - see https://bitbucket.org/ispottv/product-backend-infrastructure/pull-requests/45

Answer (score 3):

As of `v2` of `CDK` this is available by default:

> Now by default when you bootstrap an AWS account it will create a set of IAM roles for you, which the CDK will assume when performing actions in that account.

Answer (score -1):

If you have multiple stacks in your app you have to pass every stack into the cdk deploy command e.g. `cdk deploy WmStackRouteCertStack004BE231 WmStackUploadStackF8C20A98`

I don't know of a way to deploy all stacks in an app, I don't like this behavior and it's the reason I try to avoid creating multiple stacks

Comment: But this doesn't address what credentials are required to deploy multiple stacks when the stacks are to be deployed to differing acounts?

Comment: @John you can use the [cdk credential plugin](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/cdk-credential-plugin/) or even implement your own [credential provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/typescript/api/aws-cdk/credentialprovidersource.html)

Comment: interesting, I guess I misunderstood the question. We only deploy one stack at a time in our CI/CD. even though our infrastructure code is in a monorepo